# Using Regex in python to remove words containing digits, etc. from a list of lists

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop

I am writing a program that has a list of lists. Inside these lists there are words such as `'190g6'`. Also there are `'$"'` and `'$-'`. I would like to remove these words completely from each list that has similar words.

List of lists sample:

```
[['philips', '190g6'], ..., ['hero', '5long']]
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
# Train dataset
for lst in token_lists_train:
    for i, word in enumerate(lst):
        lst[i] = re.sub(r'\d', '', word)

print(token_lists_train)
```

All this does is print out the same list of lists as before, but without the numbers obviously:

```
[['philips', 'g'], ..., ['hero', 'long']]
```

So my question is how can I remove the entire word/element from the sublist, so that it looks like this:

```
[['phillips'], ..., ['hero']]
```

Comment: You should show sample input and required output to clarify your requirements. Also, don't use *ord* as a variable name - it's built-in function

Comment: This requirement _" I would like to remove these words completely from each list that has similar words."_ is rather unclear, you should clarify your intent with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for the tips for asking questions :)

Comment: So `'5long'` should not be removed but altered to `'long'`?

Comment: So sorry I made a mistake when typing. '5long' should not be altered to 'long', but should the completely removed from the sublist. I have updated the question to show the desired output.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also a bit unsure about the requirement regarding `'$"'` and `'$-'`: Do you want to remove all strings that contain these exact strings too? In a comment to an answer you state _"remove each element of a sublist that does not contain only letters"_ - that would be a bit different (but easier). Could you clarify?

Comment: Every word in the sublists that do not consist of only letters needs to be removed. The intended outputted list of lists should consist of nothing but letters from a-z in the "sentences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with the requirement in the comment: *"The intended outputted list of lists should consist of nothing but letters from a-z in the "sentences""*.

You could either build a pattern that matches strings you want to exclude or include:

```py
import re

re_exclude = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z]")
re_include = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]*$")
```

With that you could use `re.search` and a comprehension

```py
token_lists_train = [
    [token for token in tokens if not re_exclude.search(token)]
    for tokens in token_lists_train
]
```

or `re.match` with `filter`

```py
token_lists_train = [
    list(filter(re_include.match, tokens)) for tokens in token_lists_train
]
```

But there's a caveat: if all strings in a sublist have to be excluded then you'll have an empty list in the result. If you want to avoid that, you have to switch to something like

```py
new_token_lists_train = []
for tokens in token_lists_train:
    if tokens := [token for token in tokens if not re_exclude.search(token)]:
        new_token_lists_train.append(tokens)
token_lists_train = new_token_lists_train
```

or

```py
new_token_lists_train = []
for tokens in token_lists_train:
    if tokens := list(filter(re_include.match, tokens)):
        new_token_lists_train.append(tokens)
token_lists_train = new_token_lists_train
```

instead.

I almost forgot: you most likely don’t even need regex, `str.isalpha` should do the same:

```py
token_lists_train = [
    [token for token in tokens if token.isalpha()]
    for tokens in token_lists_train
]
```

Comment: I tried the last method, but it still keeps the g from 190g6. I will try the other methods.

Comment: @PålChristianLøken Then you’re doing something wrong: I‘ve tested all the code in the answer with your sample and they all work?

Comment: This answer worked, and gave me the results I was looking for. Thank you! I had to restart the notebook and run the entire program again for it to work. So that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

You have to use the return value (str). Like:

```
import re
for i in range(len(token_lists_train)):
    for i2 in range(len(token_lists_train[i])):
        token_lists_train[i][i2] = re.sub("\d", "", token_lists_train[i][i2])
    token_lists_train[i] = [x for x in token_lists_train[i] if x] # remove empty strings
print(token_lists_train)
```

This makes `[['190g6']]` to `[['g']]`.

Comment: Thank you, this puts me on the right path! :)

Comment: @PålChristianLøken I have edited my answer, so that each element of a sublist is not an empty list.

Comment: This still does not remove the word entirely, I am still left with 'g' inside the sublist. I will see if I can work something out from your answer. Thank you